# ImportError: cannot import name - Works in one place but not in the other one

Tags: python, python-import

So I have this directory structure:

```
proj/
|
---/subDirA
   |
   ---__init__.py
   ---fileA.py
|
---/subDirB
   |
   ---__init__.py
   ---fileB.py
|
---start.py
```

So what I'm trying to do is from fileB.py import a function in FileA.py. So I tried this:

```
from subDirA.fileA import funct
```

When I do this I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name funct
```

But If I do this instead:

```
from subDirA.fileA import *
```

I dont get the error.. Can some one explain why am I getting this error?

**Note**

The file FileA.py only has two functions, the first function I import it when I run start.py using from subDirA.fileA import funct. I get the error when I run start.py and in fileB.py I try to import the second function using from subDirA.fileA import funct2

Answer (score 1):

There is no `funct` on your `fileA` module object at import-time.  While circular imports are the most common cause of this problem, it is also possibly a typo, or one of a few other issues.

If you import the module as a whole and refer to `funct` as `fileA.funct`, the issue might go away because then `fileA.funct` will only need to be available at run-time instead of import-time.

You might also try doing a `print(dir(fileA))` immediately after importing it to see what things are in it at that point.  You might also put a `print()` immediately after the definition of `funct` in `fileA.py` to see whether the definition is executed before you get this error:

```
def funct(args):
    do_stuff()
print('funct() declared!')
```

If you are trying to execute `fileB.py` by itself, you would not expect these imports to work because the working directory is not `proj`.  The working directory must be `proj` for these imports to resolve correctly.  However, that is clearly not the issue here or you would not be able to do a star-import.

Comment: See the Python FAQ questions [here](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-import-in-a-module) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-can-i-have-modules-that-mutually-import-each-other), and also a bunch of questions on SO about circular imports. In this case, the simplest solution, as long as you're not calling `funct` as part of your top-level code, is to just `from subDirA import fileA` and use `fileA.funct`.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, in this case fileB is importing a function in fileA and start.py is importing a second function from fileA. fileA does not import fileB. Is this the same problem ? and if it is how can improve it.

Comment: @vic: Ah, I misinterpreted your question.  I'm going to rewrite the answer in a moment, so abarnert's links probably won't make sense after that.

Comment: @Kevin tried importing the module as a whole and didn't work. But if I remove the SubDirA directory and move the fileA.py to the top level directory I was able to import it in start.py and fileB.py..